# Java Button adds label when clicked after being reized or dragged or something

Tags: java, applet, awt

I have a simple code here which adds a label after being clicked. it works fine, but in order to the label to be added i have to drag or reize the window after clicking the button.

Here is my code:

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class server01 extends Applet implements ActionListener {
    Label helloLabel = new Label("applet v 0.0.1 | created for testing purpose");
    Label hello2Label = new Label("this applet will be up-to-date.");
    Button buttonButton = new Button("START" + " Button");
    Label buttonLabel = new Label("Starting server...");

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void init() {
        setBackground(Color.black);
        setForeground(Color.white);
        buttonButton.setForeground(Color.black);
        add(helloLabel);
        add(hello2Label);
        add(buttonButton);
        buttonButton.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == buttonButton) {
            add(buttonLabel);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you download a file pointed by stranger? If you want some help with code then post that code as plain text. Also try to make it  [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: i said in the post i cant beacuse for some reason it wont allow it. maybe its too long or something?

Comment: i cant post it its too long for commect, cant answer untill 7 hours has passed, and it says its not correctly formatted. my only chance if you download that link and view the code

Comment: Try pasting it in http://pastebin.com/ and give us link to it.

Comment: Also don't try to post code as comment/answer. Instead use [[edit]] option to add it to your question.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/JvZDhYkB

Comment: dafuq how did you edit my post are you an admin?

Comment: On SO users with hight reputation can do many things. In case someone try to "troll" others can fix it. It is easy and brilliant system :) You can find more info about privileges here http://stackoverflow.com/privileges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the validate method after making gui changes so that the applet can check if it is still rendered correctly.
Doing a resize will basically do the same thing.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == buttonButton) {
            add(buttonLabel);
            validate();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use repaint() method in actionPerformed() - (At the method ending) method.
It will repaint the applet window and will run again adding your label.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{
    /*
       your code here..
    */
    repaint();
}
```